# Execute ffmpeg in AWS ec2 instance windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg

Im trying to execute ffmpeg command on amazon's windows ec2 instance using elastic beanstalk. 
I intend to merge multiple videos into a single video using a .net application.

I cant see the file being created in the folder, so cant confirm if ffmpeg is working. The merging is working perfectly on local deployment and i can view the merged video.
I have configured my deployment for the required permission of file creation rights (.ebextensions) and it is working.

Im not sure what i need to do to allow execution of ffmpeg command, and im stuck here. Ive been through the forum and found similar links related to linux but not windows.

Being a newbie im really not sure how to proceed.
Are there any permission/steps i need to perform to allow ffmpeg command to execute on ec2 instance. If any? please share.

-

Comment: I would suggest strongly to try to move this to Linux. Even if your whole server is on .net, use a second worker tier EB to just run FFMPEG on the background (which I am sure you want to do anyway). In my case, my server just sends a message to the worker (using SQS) and the worker basically just handles the FFMPEG (get file(s), run ffmpeg, upload files). My worker uses Docker, to ensure ffmpeg is installed as I want (https://github.com/ampervue/docker-python34-ffmpeg)

Comment: I've come far enough, and its not possible to move to Linux. Please suggest any other way.

Comment: Its working flawlessly on local deployment, why isn't it on the ec2 server. I haven't installed ffmpeg, im directly using the .exe path for execution. Problem is im not getting any error in the logs either that could lead me to a possible solution.